# Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:

Tags: r, archlinux

I have Archlinux and I try to run `install.packages("zoo")` and I get the following error message :

> Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
>     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
>     libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I know this problem has already been asked on this site but I can't find a working answer.

```
capabilities("tcltk")
# tcltk 
#  TRUE

library(tcltk)
```

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
>         call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
>         error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
>         libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>       Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’

Any idea on how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you installed that package? Here is the file listed you need to install `tcltk`https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/tk/files/

Comment: @J_F I installed the package tk and it worked, I was trying to install tcltk beforehand.. thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Archlinux offers the needed package your system is searching for.

1. Install [this](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/tk/) package on your system
2. Subsequent install `tcltk` in R via `install.packages("tcltk")`.
3. Now you are able to install the package `zoo` completely: `install.packages("zoo")`.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure with step 2? `tcltk` cannot be installed normally using `install.packages`: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is a base package, and should not be updated`

Comment: You can first check whether you need tcltk by running `capabilities()["tcltk"]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mirror should be selected first.
So if you see "please select a cran mirror for use in this session", use `chooseCRANmirror()`. This works for me. The error only happens in the console, not in Rstudio.